# How to use $exists in derived query method for mongodb in spring data

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've a query in repo like below,

```java
public class Boo {
  EnumType enumType;
}

public class Foo extends Boo {
  String id;
}

public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

  Foo findFooById(String id)
}
```

I need to add another condition to check if field `$exists: false`, I've done it using an explicit `@Query` - but is it possible to use it within query method itslef (maybe `findFooByIdAndEnumTypeNotExists` or something)?

```java
public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

  @Query(value="{ id: ?0, enumType: { $exists: false } }")
  Foo findFooById(String id)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, that is possible! You can find all the keywords supported for query derivation [in MongoDB in the official sprign-data-mongdb documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries).

P.S: So your example (i.e. `findFooByIdAndAnotherFieldExists`) is correct :)

Comment: Sorry, it should've been `..NotExists..`, I've corrected it. When I use `NotExists` I get an error saying `Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property 'not' found for type 'EnumType' Traversed path: Foo.EnumType`

Comment: I think the issue is with inheritance, my `Foo` is actually `Foo extends Boo`

Comment: @opensourcegeek You should not use `NotExists` - there is no such token in the query derivation algorithm. You need to use `Exists` in the query name and just pass `false`. Regarding inheritance - yes, if you try to use `Exists` on parent property, then this would not work. It is not supported in spring data Mongodb now. Did I answer your question?)

Comment: yes you've answered my question, is supporting inheritance in the road map?

Comment: as far as I know it is not considered now... but you can check in spri g-data-mongodb issues page: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/issues

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```java
public interface FooRepository extends MongoRepository<Foo, String> {

        Foo findFooByIdAndAnotherFieldExists(String id, String anotherField);

}
```

Comment: As it's currently written your answer doesn't seem to add anything that the other answer didn't state.